# Any compactification is equivalent to some compactification which is a subset of some $I^m$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

How would I show, that any compactification is equivalent to some compactification which is a subset of some $I^m$?

I would appreciate it, if someone told me, whether this approach seems fine:

Say I have a space $X$ and a compactification $(Y,c_1)$, with $c_1$ an embedding of $X$ in some space $Y$, and $Y$ is the closure of $c(X)$.   Now I know $Y$ is a compact space, and so I can embed it in $I^{w(Y)}$ with some function $l$. So I have a homeomorphism between $Y$ and $l(Y)$, $l(Y)$ a subset of $I^{w(Y)}$.

I take the restriction of $l$ to $c_1(X)$ and call it $j$. This restriction is a homeomorphism (I think you could show this from both $l$ and it's inverse being continuous, so their restrictions would be continuous?) from $c_1(X)$ to some set $B=j(c_1(X)) \subset l(Y)$, and so if I define $c_2 = j \circ c_1$, it is an embedding of $X$ in $I^{w(Y)}$. Clearly $\bar{B} \subset l(Y)$, as $l(Y)$ is closed, because it's a compact set in a compact Hausdorff space (because it's a continuous image of Y compact), and because $l$ is continuous and $c_1(X)$ is dense in $Y$, we get that $\bar{B} = l(Y)$ (from continuity - closure of $B$ in $I^{w(Y)}$ contains image of $c_1(X)$ with $l$) .

So $(l(Y),c_2)$ is a compactification of $X$, there's a homeomorphism to it from $Y$, and for any $x \in X$, we get $l(c_1(x)) = j(c_1(x)) = c_2(x)$, because $c_1(x) \in c_1(X)$ and so $j$ is equal to $l$ there.

Thus $(Y, c_1)$ and $(l(Y), c_2)$ are equivalent compactifications of $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is essentially correct. I assume your definition of compact includes Hausdorff (as otherwise the embedding isn't true), and so $X$ is completely regular (which is necessary and sufficient to prove that it has a Hausdorff compactification at all). Better name these restrictions (or make it clear "space" = "completely regular $T_1$ space" (a.k.a Tychonoff space).

Presumably you have only shown the embedding theorem for compact Hausdorff spaces? It now follows from your reasoning that any completely regular space $X$ (or any space with a compact Hausdorff compactification, equivalently) has an embedding into $I^{w(X)}$ as well (as $w(X) \le w(Y)$ when $(Y,c)$ is a compactification of $X$).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Yes, I presume that compact includes Hausdorff here.

Actually no, I have seen the fact that you can embed a $X$ Tychonoff space into $I^{w(X)}$ first - I used that this way : $Y$ is compact, therefore it's Tychonoff, therefore I can embed it in $I^w{Y}$ with some function $l$ , and because this embedding is a continuous function, $l(Y)$ is compact. Perhaps showing my claim in the original post this way is excessively complicated? I don't know.

Comment: I must say I don't understand your second paragraph. From my reasoning, I've found an embedding of $X$ in $I^{w(Y)}$, for some $Y$ compactification, but I don't know whether I can find an $Y$ of the same weight as $X$ (for that, I would have to know the embedding theorem we're talking about first). 
I do have an homeomorphism of $X$ with some subset of $I^{w(Y)}$ that is of weight $w(X)$, and we do know $w(X)\le w(Y)$, so maybe I could somehow use that to show that I can embed $X$ in $I^{w(X)}$ ?